# Fix Oneboxing for Area 51 links with referrals

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, onebox

I was trying to drum up support for [the Indian Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39575/indian-culture?referrer=LV4zRwgvVgvIxr8VY2IctQ2) proposal in an Indian-language chat room I'd found. Anyway, I realized that while I could post [the image](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/39575.png) and the hyperlink, I couldn't post a hyperlinked image, which is sort of needed if you post the image, since it had a nice, yellow "support this" button on it that you feel like clicking. `<a href=..><img></a>` didn't work either.

So, could you add Area 51 oneboxing support for? Maybe not a onebox, just show the linked advertisement when an Area 51 (possibly referrer) link is posted.

EDIT: It seems that oneboxing works, just not for referrals. Fix please? Or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Maybe have the referrals show the site ad, and have a nonreferral link show a onebox.

Comment: Area 51 oneboxing [already exists](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/928890#928890), it just doesn't work if you've included a referral parameter.

Comment: @TimStone: Aah. Any reason for that?